Mockito blocks micronaut property injection
Basic problem:
When using @Mock and @InjectMocks in a test, you have to use @Spy on all the beans you still want to inject normally. Problem is that this does not work with @Property you can't use @Spy on @Property. But when there is no @Spy the property value of "envValue" will be null. So what to do?
@MicronautTest
@Property(name = "someEnvName", value = "0")
public class TestFooBar {
    @Spy
    @Inject
    private Foo foo; //bean that is injected inside Bar

    @Mock
    private ClassToBeMocked mocked; //bean that is injected inside Bar

    @Spy
    @Property(name = "someEnvName")
    private Long envValue; //some property that is used in Bar. --> throws an error

    @InjectMocks
    private Bar bar; //class to test



Ok. The solution is like suggested on the micronaut docu
(https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-test/4.0.0-M8/guide/index.html#junit5)
Instead of using @Spy  on all "normal" implementations. I just had to use
    @MockBean(ClassToBeMockedImpl.class)
    public ClassToBeMocked classToBeMocked() {
        return mock(ClassToBeMocked.class);
    }

on the class I want o mock. So all the field injection were uncessary.
